# assign/alter multiple entries in a list efficiently (`Position` is slow)

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Given a list (e.g. of integers) `x` and a list of `0`s and `1`s `i` (of the same length as `x`), how can I alter those entries of `x` where the value of `i` is 1?

For example, the code

```
n=10^8; x=RandomInteger[{-100,100},n]; i=RandomInteger[{0,1},n];
y=RandomInteger[{-100,100},n]; ByteCount@{x,i,y}
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[i=Flatten[Position[i,1],1]]
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[x[[i]]=y[[i]]]
```

shows that for 2.4GB of data, `Position` spends 22sec and 10GB, whilst assignment spends only 0.85sec and 0.8GB. The former seems excessive. Is there a better way to do this? Python has this built-in (when `i` is a `numpy` array of booleans).

Comment: why not just `x = x (1 - i)`?

Comment: `x[[Pick[Range@n,i,1]]=0`

Code Wolfram like Wolfram, not Python, else it's Cobols all the way down...

Comment: @kglr Uf, you're right, `x=x*(1-i)+y*i`. However, this only works if `y` is of the same length as `x`. But what if the length of `y` is the number of ones in `i` and I want to do `x[[i]]=y`?

Comment: @Leo, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 10^8; x = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, n]; i = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, n];
z1 = z2 = z3 = x;

AbsoluteTiming @ MaxMemoryUsed[z1 = z1 (1 - i)]
```

> ```
> {2.00115, 1600000424}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming @ MaxMemoryUsed[z3[[Random`Private`PositionsOf[i, 1]]] = 0]
```

> ```
> {3.52455, 1599995920}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming @ MaxMemoryUsed[z2[[Pick[Range @ n, i, 1]]] = 0] (* ciao's comment*)
```

> ```
> {4.8352, 1655914552}
> ```

```
z1 == z2 == z3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The last two also work for the case where *"the length of `y` is the number of ones in `i` and I want to do `x[[i]] = y`"*.

Comment: Much appreciated! Just one more question: if `Position` and `Random`Private`PositionsOf` do the same thing, but the latter is way more effective, why doesn't it replace the former as an official command?

Comment: @Leo, `Position` handles arbitrary inputs' ``Random`Private`PositionsOf`` (seems to be ) limited to integer vectors.